# Replace text between line breaks with <p></p> and <b></b>

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, handlebars.js

I'm doing a Handlebars.js Helper in which I receive a string with line breaks (`\n`) and double line breaks (`\n\n`). I want to replace the text preceded by a double line break and followed by one line break with the same text, but between `<p><b></b></p>`. In other words, I want titles and subtitles in "bold paragraphs" and the rest in "regular paragraphs". I want this to affect overlapping matches too, but I'm afraid the `.replace()` method and my RegEx level are not enough.

This is my string:

```
"Jamie Smith (known by the stage name Jamie xx) is an English music producer and remix artist, who is known both as a solo act and as a member of the London-based band The xx.
\n\n
Career:
\n\n
2005 - 2009:
\n
Smith's musical career began in 2005 when he joined The xx accompanying old schoolmates Romy Madley Croft, Oliver Sim and Baria Qureshi of the Elliott School in London, notable for alumni including Hot Chip, Burial and Four Tet. He first used the stage name Jamie xx in July 2009 in a promotional mix for the band's début album xx released on the FACT mix series of the FACT Magazine. The mixtape was compiled by Jamie Smith and featured, amongst others, four tracks credited to Jamie xx - one own-production and three remixes. The xx album went on to become platinum in the UK. Afterward, Jamie Smith went on to do more remix work for artists like Florence + The Machine, Adele, Jack Peñate and Glasser.
\n\n
2010 - Present:
\n
In late 2010, a Jamie xx remix of the song \"NY Is Killing Me\" from Gil Scott-Heron's last album I'm New Here aired on radio stations across the UK and Europe. The remix of \"I'll Take Care Of U\" followed in January 2011. Both singles drew the attention of the general public and the critics."
```

And I want to get this:

```
"<p>
Jamie Smith (known by the stage name Jamie xx) is an English music producer and remix artist, who is known both as a solo act and as a member of the London-based band The xx.
</p>
<p><b>
Career:
</b></p>
<p><b>
2005 - 2009:
</b></p>
<p>
Smith's musical career began in 2005 when he joined The xx accompanying old schoolmates Romy Madley Croft, Oliver Sim and Baria Qureshi of the Elliott School in London, notable for alumni including Hot Chip, Burial and Four Tet. He first used the stage name Jamie xx in July 2009 in a promotional mix for the band's début album xx released on the FACT mix series of the FACT Magazine. The mixtape was compiled by Jamie Smith and featured, amongst others, four tracks credited to Jamie xx - one own-production and three remixes. The xx album went on to become platinum in the UK. Afterward, Jamie Smith went on to do more remix work for artists like Florence + The Machine, Adele, Jack Peñate and Glasser.
</p>
<p><b>
2010 - Present:
</b></p>
<p>
In late 2010, a Jamie xx remix of the song \"NY Is Killing Me\" from Gil Scott-Heron's last album I'm New Here aired on radio stations across the UK and Europe. The remix of \"I'll Take Care Of U\" followed in January 2011. Both singles drew the attention of the general public and the critics.
</p>"
```

I'm using JavaScript because it is part of a Handlebars.js Helper, but I don't know if there is another way to do it.

Thank you and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is put the lines that begin with 2x `\n` into a different capture-group and examine the capture-groups in a *callback* function you give to `.replace()`. This is how you capture the different "types" of paragraphs (header or normal) into different capture groups (notice the `|` in the middle)

```
(?:\r?\n){2}([^\r\n]+)|(?:^|\r?\n)([^\r\n]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/DzgkkKRzglRBY8y6)

Then in the code you can look if Group 1 exists, if so, put `<b></b>` around it. Else, return Group 2:

```js
var subject = "Jamie Smith (known by the stage name Jamie xx) is an English music producer and remix artist, who is known both as a solo act and as a member of the London-based band The xx.\n\nCareer:\n\n2005 - 2009:\nSmith's musical career began in 2005 when he joined The xx accompanying old schoolmates Romy Madley Croft, Oliver Sim and Baria Qureshi of the Elliott School in London, notable for alumni including Hot Chip, Burial and Four Tet. He first used the stage name Jamie xx in July 2009 in a promotional mix for the band's début album xx released on the FACT mix series of the FACT Magazine. The mixtape was compiled by Jamie Smith and featured, amongst others, four tracks credited to Jamie xx - one own-production and three remixes. The xx album went on to become platinum in the UK. Afterward, Jamie Smith went on to do more remix work for artists like Florence + The Machine, Adele, Jack Peñate and Glasser.\n\n2010 - Present:\nIn late 2010, a Jamie xx remix of the song \"NY Is Killing Me\" from Gil Scott-Heron's last album I'm New Here aired on radio stations across the UK and Europe. The remix of \"I'll Take Care Of U\" followed in January 2011. Both singles drew the attention of the general public and the critics.";

var regex = /(?:\r?\n){2}([^\r\n]+)|(?:^|\r?\n)([^\r\n]+)/g;

var replace = subject.replace(regex, function(match, p1, p2) {
    return '\n<p>' + ((p1==undefined)? p2 : '<b>' + p1 + '</b>' ) + '</p>';
});

document.getElementById('out').value = replace.trim();
document.getElementById('outdiv').innerHTML = replace.trim();
```

```html
<textarea rows="15" style="width:100%" id="out"></textarea>
<div id="outdiv"></div>
```